# Extract data from Shopify into a Google Sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to get specific product fields of a JSON object to send to a google sheet. The log tells me that 'console.log(productTitle)' is undefined and that 'Error: TypeError: products.forEach' is not a function. The structure of the Shopify object is below.

```
    function getProducts() {

  //set up url
  const url = 'https://*****.myshopify.com/admin/'
  const endpoint = 'products.json'

  //set up parameters

  const params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Shopify-Access-Token': '*****'

    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true

  }

  try {

    //call the url to fetch access token

    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + endpoint, params)

    //parse the response and get the access token

    const products = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
    console.log(response)
    console.log(products)

    products.forEach(product => {

      const productTitle = product.products_title
      console.log(productTitle)

      const productId = product.products_id
      const productStatus = product.products_status



    })

    return result
  }

  catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: ' + e)
  }
}


    /* { products: 
       [ { id: 121345678910,
      title: 'Title',
      body_html: 'Body Text',
      vendor: 'Vendor Name',
      product_type: 'candyrack_generated',
      created_at: '2021-07-18T11:04:34-05:00',
      handle: 'extended-warranty-1',
      updated_at: '2022-10-11T09:15:18-05:00',
      published_at: '2021-07-18T11:04:34-05:00',
      template_suffix: 'water-pump',
      status: 'active',
      published_scope: 'web',
      tags: '',
      admin_graphql_api_id: 'gid://shopify/Product/121345678910',
      variants: 
       [ { product_id: 121345678910,
           id: 9876543210,
           title: 'Default Title',
           price: '9.95',
           sku: '',
           position: 1,
           inventory_policy: 'continue',
           compare_at_price: null,
           fulfillment_service: 'manual',
           inventory_management: null,
           option1: 'Default Title',
           option2: null,
           option3: null,
           created_at: '2021-07-20T08:43:11-05:00',
           updated_at: '2022-10-11T09:14:17-05:00',
           taxable: true,
           barcode: '',
           grams: 0,
           image_id: null,
           weight: 0,
           weight_unit: 'kg',
           inventory_item_id: 24681012,
           inventory_quantity: -708,
           old_inventory_quantity: -708,
           requires_shipping: false,
           admin_graphql_api_id: 'gid://shopify/ProductVariant/987654' } ],
      options: 
       [ { product_id: 121345678910,
           id: 909000,
           name: 'Title',
           position: 1,
           values: [Object] } ],
      images: 
       [ { product_id: 121345678910,
           id: 3693336,
           position: 1,
           created_at: '2022-04-03T08:43:29-05:00',
           updated_at: '2022-04-03T08:43:32-05:00',
           alt: null,
           width: 1080,
           height: 1080,
           src: 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0541/4132/13/products/freereplacements.png?v=164899',
           variant_ids: [],
           admin_graphql_api_id: 'gid://shopify/ProductImage/369333' } ],
      image: 
       { product_id: 121345678910,
         id: 3693336,
         position: 1,
         created_at: '2022-04-03T08:43:29-05:00',
         updated_at: '2022-04-03T08:43:32-05:00',
         alt: null,
         width: 1080,
         height: 1080,
         src: 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0541/4132/13/products/freereplacements.png?v=1648993',
         variant_ids: [],
         admin_graphql_api_id: 'gid://shopify/ProductImage/3693336' } }
    
    */
```

I would like to pull different keys into different columns to populate rows for all products. I would also like to know how to access the Finance Reports to pull into Sheets as well. I do get a successful return of all product data 'const products = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())' , can't separate the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> The log tells me that 'console.log(productTitle)' is undefined

Google Apps Script code does not run in the browser. It runs in a sandboxed environment on Google's servers, so logging works a little differently than what you might be used to in the browser. See the docs on [Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) for Apps Script.

> 'Error: TypeError: products.forEach' is not a function

Take a second look at the Shopify response. It's structured as:

```
{
   products: [...]
}
```

So your code `products = JSON.parse(...)` is actually referencing the response object, not the `products` array inside it. Try something like this:

```js
const responseObj = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
const products = responseObj.products
```

> I would like to pull different keys into different columns to populate rows for all products. I would also like to know how to access the Finance Reports to pull into Sheets as well. I do get a successful return of all product data 'const products = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())' , can't separate the data.

You are on the right track with using `forEach` to loop through the products in the `products` array (once you fix the above issue) to get individual properties of each object.

To write the data out to a Google Sheet, you'll need to explore the [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) API.

In short, you will need to structure the data from the Shopify response into a two-dimensional array to write the data to a sheet. Search Google for `two-dimensional array javascript` if you are not familiar with this concept; two-dimensional arrays are just a way of structuring tabular data, like that in a spreadsheet. Once you have your two-dimensional array, you will write it back to the Google Sheet with [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Comment: Thanks @Adam for your response and clarification. I am still not certain how I can pull specific keys or fields within the JSON object of products?

Comment: @Maicol Apologies, I missed the last part of your question. I have edited my answer above to give some guidance.

Comment: thanks again for your feedback, it is very helpful. I have been able to successfully pull the data and create the 2 dimensional array as you mentioned. If I have to pass that item or data to retrieve further data how is that structured. For example; a GET REST call  such as /admin/api/2022-10/checkouts/{checkout token or id}/payments.json needs the {checkout token or id} which I was able to do with the above code. How do I pass that data to get the data details of the payments. Many of the GET calls are structure in the same fashion.